# ng-grid complete manipulation of the field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

hi guys i have a couple of questions about ng-grid,
this is my grid-options

```
$scope.gridOptions= {
    data:'data',
    selectedItems:sel,
    multiSelect:false,
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'field1', displayName: 'field1',cellTemplate: template,  cellClass:'cellToolTip'},
        {field:'field2', cellTemplate: template, visible:false},
        { field:'field3', displayName:'field3', cellTemplate: template,  cellClass:'cellToolTip' },
        { field: 'field4', displayName: 'field4',cellTemplate: templatetest} ,
        { field: 'dataInserimento', displayName: 'Data richiesta',cellTemplate: template,  cellClass:'cellToolTip'} ,
        { displayName: 'field5', cellTemplate:'<div ><button ng-diasbled="pdfenabled" ng-click="reportpdf()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></button></div>', cellClass:'gridCell' }]
    }
}
```

and the two possible cell template are these

```
var template = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a id="gridField"  ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>';
var templatetest = '<div ng-disabled="enabled" class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a id="gridField"  ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>'
```

the data array is something similar to that one

```
[{field1:'something',
  field2:'something',
  field3:'something',
  field4:[{otherstuff:'something',morestuff:'something'}],
  field5:'something'}
  {field1:'something',
  field2:'something',
  field3:'something',
  field4:[{otherstuff:'something',morestuff:'something'}],
  field5:'something'}
  {field1:'something',
  field2:'something',
  field3:'something',
  field4:[{otherstuff:'something',morestuff:'something'}],
  field5:'something'}
  }]
```

so the first problem is: how can  i display the elements in the field4 field not like an array? is it possible to get only one or both values?
second question, it is possible to use a cell field property for another cell bind?
for example

```
if(field3==false){
    $scope.enabled=true;
}
```

Comment: What elements in `field4` do you want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your template like this:

```
var templatetest = '<div ng-disabled="enabled" class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)[0].otherstuff"></div>';
```

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCfnw6p2yJPA1X0cODl5?p=preview)

Or even better you could use a filter:

```
app.filter('somefilter', function() {
  return function(x) {
    return x[0].otherstuff + ' / ' + x[0].morestuff;
  };
});
```

in combination with this template:

```
var templatetest = '<div ng-disabled="enabled" class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)|somefilter"></div>';
```

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bH49NxD2YwwQVTuih0nR?p=preview)

Or (this includes the Answer to your second question) use row.entity to look up the full rowdata:

```
var templatetest = '<div ng-disabled="enabled" class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"> <a href="#">{{row.entity.field4[0].otherstuff+"/"+row.entity.field3}}</a></div>';
```

Here's the  final [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCfnw6p2yJPA1X0cODl5?p=preview)

Hope you can get on with this.